# Eclipse projects sharing images?

Tags: android, eclipse, image, resources

I had an Android project in eclipse, I then duplicated the project changed some of the code and updated the images, in windows explorer and eclipse the images are updated but when I run the app it uses the images from the original project, not the copy but I want the two projects to use their own images.

Any Ideas? have I missed something I needed to update in the new project?

Comment: Before cleaning your project, also try to select your project in the package explorer and hit f5, or right-click and select refresh.

Comment: And make sure they have different package names too since you intend them to be separate apps.

Answer (score 0):

In the "Build" folder you may see temporary files to build the application. Eclipse does not always correctly updates them because attributes of files may be violated.
If "project cleaning" has not helped you may delete the "Build" folder from the project folder.